# Netcdf error when calling http in scala

Tags: scala, netcdf

I am trying to get http://dd.weather.gc.ca/ensemble/naefs/grib2/raw/12/018/CMC_naefs-geps-raw_RH_TGL_2m_latlon0p5x0p5_2018070712_P018_allmbrs.grib2 file with NetCDF:

```
 def read(path: String): NetcdfDataset = {
    NetcdfDataset.openDataset(path)
  }
```

but I get

> java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 4:
>   http://dd.weather.gc.ca/ensemble/naefs/grib2/raw/12/018/CMC_naefs-geps-raw_RH_TGL_2m_latlon0p5x0p5_2018070712_P018_allmbrs.grib2

I have `"edu.ucar" % "netcdfAll" % "4.6.3"`. What should I do to get this file? I already tried to load grib2 file from disk with this method and it goes OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the function `NetcdfDataset.openDataset` doesn't accept URLs, but only local paths. I suggest you download the `.grib2` file to your computer and then pass the path to the downloaded file to the `openDataset` function,

e.g.

```
NetcdfDataset.openDataset("/home/kuba/Downloads/CMC_naefs-geps-raw_RH_TGL_2m_latlon0p5x0p5_2018070712_P018_allmbrs.grib2")
```

Comment: I know that I can download it and then open with this function. But `NetcdfDataset.openDataset` under the hood uses `NetcdfDataset.openFile` which accept URLs (this is what documentation say) and I thought that I could use it.